# Query with cumulative total revenue in Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data look like this:

```
Platform,Userid,In-app Product,Country,Currency,Timestamp,Transaction Receipt,Price
IOS,5.669802981,offer4,US,USD,28/03/2017 02:30,240200367307.75848,1.99
ANDROID,6.831350998,offer4,US,USD,27/03/2017 23:23,436138823984.4136,3.99
ANDROID,6.831233793,pack2.cash,CA,USD,27/03/2017 18:32,192318559985.1093,4.112
```

I want to find the cumulative sum of price per day.

Any idea on how to create a query that gives cumulative revenue per day?

Maybe i need to use a window function?
I tried something like this:

```
select date_trunc('day',"Timestamp") as day,"Price",sum("Price") as cumul OVER (order by day) FROM cleandataset ORDER BY day
```

But it doesnt work
For example i want the results to be something like this

```
day price cumulativetotalrevenue
1/1/2016 10 10
2/1/2016 5  15
3/1/2016 20 45
```

Comment: Please add what is the expected output. Where you are stuck?

Comment: @TejaGoudKandula Take a look now

Comment: I'm lost.  I see `1.99` for `price` in the original data but not in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select date_trunc('day', "Timestamp") as day, "Price",
       sum("Price") over (order by date_trunc('day', "Timestamp"))
from cleandataset 
order by day;
```

Your version had some typos.

Answer (score 0):

#### There is two ways to calculate the cumulative revenue here

1. To output the cumulative revenue for each day for each transactions, your initial query was almost right but you misplaced the 'as cumul'.
   Try :

```
SELECT DATE("Timestamp") AS day, "Price", SUM("Price") OVER (ORDER BY DATE("Timestamp")) AS cumulative
FROM cleandataset
ORDER BY DATE("Timestamp");
```

---

2. If you want to calculate the cumulative revenue for each day disregarding each sale's price, you can use :

```
SELECT day, daily_price, SUM(daily_price) OVER (ORDER BY day)
FROM (
         SELECT DATE("Timestamp") AS day, SUM("Price") AS daily_price
         FROM cleandataset
         GROUP BY DATE("Timestamp")
) req
ORDER BY day;
```

Comment: "2016-12-01" 286.72983999999997
"2016-12-02" 246.11825999999996
"2016-12-03" 275.05049

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Yeah my bad, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @xaroulisgekas Just edited my answer, does this work for you ?